# GeoNetwork is not loading

Tags: geonetwork, tomcat

I'm trying to get GeoNetwork working but no success. Here is the workaround I did to install GeoNetwork :

1. Install Tomcat
2. Download geonetwork.war
3. Deploy the war inside Tomcat
4. /geonetwork folder created
5. Run http://localhost:8080/geonetwork

It took several minutes to render this error :

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<apiError>
<code>runtime_exception</code>
<description>Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space</description>
<message>NestedServletException</message>
</apiError>
```

Can't figure out what may cause this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a pretty clear error message "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" - you have run out of memory for the JVM heap.

You will need to allocate more memory to the JVM using `-Xmx6g` or any other amount you care to use. See also the GeoNetWork manual [discussion](https://geonetwork-opensource.org/manuals/2.10.4/eng/users/admin/advanced-configuration/index.html#advanced-configuration-for-larger-catalogs).

Comment: How can I increase memory to JVM using the -Xmx6g?

Comment: in your setenv.sh or setenv.bat file the same as any other tomcat environment variable

Comment: I set it manualy from the control panel. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @zakariamouqcit Please note that the memory that you are allocating will be divided to both heap and non-heap memory (around 50/50) which means you should assign twice to get what you need in heap area. Take look at this post https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/11/memory-footprint-of-the-jvm